# Get yahoo comments with web scraping

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to get the news comments on yahoo, where there is a link "See reactions", with the following id: "caascommtbar-wide" and tried to get the element with CasperJS, Selenium, ScrapySharp, to click on the link and display the comments, but in those tools you never find the element and I've even tried using the XPath

CasperJS:

```
       casper.then (function () {
            if (this.exists ('a.caascommtbar-anchor')) {
                  this.echo ("It exists");
            } else
                 this.echo ("It Does not Exist");
       });

       casper.then (function () {
       // Click on 1st result link
            this.click ('a.caascommtbar-anchor');
      });
```

Selenium:

```
driver.FindElement (By.Id ("caascommtbar-anchor")). Click ();
```

Does anyone know why you can not access this part of the HTML code where the comments are located?

It should be noted that the same thing happens to me when trying to access the Facebook comments contained in the news forums.

Comment: They might not be loaded yet, they might be loaded via ajax

Comment: Please provide link to page

Comment: this is the page:
https://es-us.vida-estilo.yahoo.com/instagram-cierra-la-cuenta-de-una-modelo-por-ser-gorda-103756072.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Isaac said the part of pages are loaded asynchronously, so you should implement waitFor steps in your code. Here is the code that does just that.

```
var url = "https://es-us.vida-estilo.yahoo.com/instagram-cierra-la-cuenta-de-una-modelo-por-ser-gorda-103756072.html";
var casper = require('casper').create({
  viewportSize: {width: 1280, height: 800},
});

casper.start(url, function() {
  this.echo('Opened page');
});

casper.waitForSelector('a.comments-title', function() {
  this.click('.comments-title');
});

casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list > li', function() {
  this.echo(this.getHTML('ul.comments-list'));
});

casper.run();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That was the answer, the problem was why the page was not loaded yet and I had to wait, I'm new with casperjs.
Now I have the problem when trying to remove all comments along with their answers, but can not find an algorithm to help me.
Try to press all the answer buttons, but only get the first answers to the first comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was why the page was not loaded yet and I had to wait, I'm new with casperjs.

Now I have the problem when trying to remove all comments along with their answers, but can not find an algorithm to help me. Try to press all the answer buttons, but only get the first answers to the first comments.

```
casper.waitForSelector('button.showMore', function () {
     this.click('.showMore');
}, function onWaitTimeout() {        
});

var buttons;
casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list', function getLinks() {
buttons = this.evaluate(function ()
{         
   var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('replies-button');
   buttons = Array.prototype.map.call(buttons, function (button) {
   button.click();      
   casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list', function () {
         casper.wait(3000, function () {
        });
   });
   return button.getAttribute('class');
   });
        return buttons;
   });
}, function onWaitTimeout() {

});

function wait5seconds() {
   casper.wait(3000, function () {      
   });
}
casper.waitForSelector('ul.comments-list > li', function () {  
   var x = this.getHTML('ul.comments-list');    
   this.echo(x);
}, function onWaitTimeout() {        
});

casper.run();
```